# Prove that cartesian product of dual spaces is the dual space of cartesian product

Tags: functional-analysis

Let we're dealing with a finite cartesian product. Please, Prove that cartesian product of dual spaces is the dual space of cartesian product.

Example, for two space:
$$(X × Y)^*\cong X^* × Y^*$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please also give your understanding about the question and any attempt to solve it. This will not attract downvotes to your question and will also prevent it from being closed. For more information on how to ask a good question, you may refer: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Considering that your definition of "dual space" is the set of all linear functionals, notice that $\left( X \times Y \right)^*$ is the set of all linear functions $f : X \times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $X$ and $Y$ are NLS. And, the set $X^* \times Y^*$ is the set of all tuples $\left( f, g \right)$, there $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g: Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are linear functionals. Therefore, in general, these sets cannot be equal. However, you may ask if they are isomorphic as vector spaces and homeomorphic as topological spaces.